# Drupal 8 SQL Statements With Spaces In Column Name

Tags: sql, postgresql, drupal, drupal-8

I'm trying to use Drupal's sql commands to update a table but the column names utilize spaces.  For example, one of the columns is named "Phase 1."  Drupal passes the command as if the name was "Phase1" and I can't quite figure out why.
I'm on Drupal 8 and I'm using postgresql.

Here is a portion of the code:

```
\Drupal::database()->update('table')
                    ->condition('test', $test)
                    ->fields([
                            "Phase 1" => $phase1,
                    ])
            ->execute();
```

Comment: I think if you make the names "/"Phase 1/"" with the escaped quotes, it should work.  At least it does in PGAdmin if you have spaces in column names.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you need to you double quotes, when name contains whitespace:

```
... where "Phase 1" = 1 ...
```

So try this:

```
\Drupal::database()->update('table')
                    ->condition('test', $test)
                    ->fields([
                            '"Phase 1"' => $phase1,
                    ])
            ->execute();
```